# How to create the array of the arrangement function?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, programming

I have to create the function arrangement in C++ : the number of admissible p-lists in n objects.

$$ar(n,p)=\begin{pmatrix}n\\ p\end{pmatrix}\times p!=n\times...\times(n-p+1)$$

But I prefer this formula : $$\frac{n!}{(n-p)!}$$

the function is `int** arrangement(int m)` constructing the array of arrangement values for $n=0,1,...,m$ and $0\le p\le n$. For instance `arrangement(4)` should give :

```
1
1 1
1 2 2
1 3 6 6
1 4 12 24 24
```

I don't understand the second line. It should be $\{\begin{pmatrix}4\\ 0\end{pmatrix}\times0!=1,\begin{pmatrix}4\\ 1\end{pmatrix}\times1!=4\}$ and so on , isn't it ?

Comment: You can take n from user then create one loop for n! and another loop for (n-p)! Where p will have another loop to increment. And that can be put in a class to keep it private.

Comment: ${n! \over \left(n - p\right)!}$ is evaluated in $\texttt{C++}$ as
$$
\texttt{round(\exp(lgamma(n + 1) - lgamma(n - p + 1)))}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The second line is the case $p=0, n=1$ and $p=1,n=1$, i.e.
$$\binom{1}{1-0}=1 \ \ \ \ \binom{1}{1-1}=1.$$